# I18N, L10N and database, how to?

Tags: php, zend-framework, database-design, localization, internationalization

I'm going to update/rewrite an existing hard coded websites.

I need to localize it, but the application will serve different contents depending on the country/language.

What would be the best way to work with this?

I though to add a column in my database for each localized created content such "locale = en_GB" or use a different database for each application.

Any feedbacks?

---

**Edit**

Let's say an application. Ok.

I want this application to have the same features but in different countries.

The content is provided by a community, so there is no way to translate it, and is not application wide, only available for the application configured to work with the country C.

Country = One Domain Name = Specific Content = Same Features as the others.

I know I could configure each application to use a different database, but I imagine if I need to add a column to add features, I'll have to do it on each countries.

If I add a column to localize content, I'll be able to fetch the localized content whatever the application is by specifying the currently used locale.

I'm going to use Zend_Locale & Zend_Translate/gettext, so I know how to do it in php.

Both solution have their pros & cons but I've not enough experiences in such application to choose the right way.

Comment: The question is very broad. Can you give some more details on what should be considered localized content. And more importantly, how localized content will be provided to the application? For instance: will it be a sort of CMS setup, where content managers will be able to insert localized content for the application?

Answer (score 3):

The locale is **rarely** part of the database.

The locale is part of the presentation of data in the database.

So each user provides their locale.

Your application uses ordinary localization to translate numbers and dates.

Your application uses ordinary i18n libraries to translate the database text and application messages into localized text.

Comment: `The locale is rarely part of the database.` Unless it's a CMS setup, where content managers will be able to input localized content for the application.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: True.  But that's not a "column in my database for each localized created content", is it?

Comment: Well, as I've commented to the questioner; the question is too broad to figure out what OP has in mind exactly. So I don't know really. Could be OP *is* looking for something like that. If not, then I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first approach: mark each different language with a specific column. Easier to manage and more flexible than managing different databases/tables.

On the layouts: you can use PHP's [gettext()](http://php.net/gettext) functions or you can create different templates for each language if you want.